# Remotely install CentOS 7 (VNC) - Can't boot

Tags: boot, centos, grub, remote-control, centos-7

I'm trying to remotely install CentOS 7 (on another CentOS 7) on a machine following the procedure below...

http://www.danpros.com/2016/02/how-to-install-centos-7-remotely-using-vnc

... which basically is boot the machine using the bootstrap files below...

```
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/isolinux/vmlinuz -O vmlinuz-7
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/isolinux/initrd.img -O initrd-7.img
```

... and access it using VNC.

However, after rebooting the machine using the above boot scheme the following error occurs...

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Switch Root.
See 'systemctl status initrd-switch-root.service' for details.
Warning: /dev/root does not exist

Generating "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt"

Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue.
Type "journalctl" to view system logs.
You might want to save "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt" to a USB stick or /boot 
after mounting them and attach it to a bug report.
```

Inside the file...

```
/etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

... there is the following content...

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

menuentry 'NetInstall' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod xfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='hd0,msdos1' 0c9d9ace-9666-4977-ab1c-892f62880970
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0c9d9ace-9666-4977-ab1c-892f62880970
    fi
    linux16 /vmlinuz-7 inst.vnc inst.vncpassword=12345678 inst.headless ip=172.16.13.128::172.16.13.2:255.255.255.0::eno16777736:none nameserver=8.8.8.8 inst.repo=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/ inst.lang=en_US inst.keymap=us
    initrd16 /initrd-7.img
}
```

**Any ideas why the above error occurs?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a thread with a lot of information about this issue on this link...

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=61089

Basically the problem occurs because the version of the bootstrap files below...

```
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/isolinux/vmlinuz -O vmlinuz-7
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/isolinux/initrd.img -O initrd-7.img
```

I started using these versions and the problem stopped...

```
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/isolinux/vmlinuz -O vmlinuz-7
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/isolinux/initrd.img -O initrd-7.img
```